# How to wire a 3 way switch that was a light fan and now only a light. Way to many may wires in one box, not sure how to connect

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I know how to wire a normal 3 way switch but this one has be baffled.  One of the boxes is basic red/black/white but the other one has **TWO** red/black/white wires coming in[image] and a black/white wire coming in the bottom.  I assume the black/white bottom wires are the source and that I should connect that black to the dark screw.  I have not idea how to connect the remaining combination of wires.  Do I piggy back?  Help?

Comment: Have all the old switches & fixture already been removed?

Comment: Hi Free man, Yes they have.

Comment: I don't see how that's "a lot of wires", it looks like the absolute bare minimum possible for a 3-way light switch + support for a separately switched light/fan.

Comment: But I do not need the fan/light anymore.  I am just installing a ceiling light,

Answer (score 1):

Let's get some colored tape, okay?  A [5-pack variety pack](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-1-2-in-x-20-ft-Colored-Electrical-Tape-5-Pack-GTPC-550/100054213) is $4-5.

Now, on the lamp, mark the black wire RED. Red is the *preferred* color for switched-hot, and presumably you want the lamp to be switched.

BLACK is preferred for always-hot.   YELLOW is Harper's preferred color for travelers.

These "preferred" colors are not Code requirements, but *holy cow, they make life easier - especially next time you are in the box!*

Up at the lamp, cap off the black wire with a small (orange) wire nut - won't be needing it.  Attach lamp white to ceiling white with a wire nut.  Attach lamp red (former black) to ceiling red with a wire nut.  Attach grounds and we're done there.

Now, you have no earthly idea which of the /3 cables goes to the 3-way vs ceiling, do you?   OK.

- On the remote 3-way switch, cap off all 3 wires individually. Stuff is about to start getting hot.
- Pick ONE of the 3-wire cables in the main switch box. Wire nut its white wire to the "supply" white.  Wire-nut its red wire to "supply" black.   Go turn the breaker back on.
- Does the lamp light up?  We got the right cable, woot! We're done.
- If not, turn power back off, unhook, and try the last step  with the other 3-wire cable.

Now you have identified the /3 cable going to the ceiling.  In the main box, cap off its black wire, you won't be using it until you sell the house.

Also disconnect the black from red wire that you temporarily nutted for testing.

The remaining /3 cable is the 3-way branch.  On both ends, use yellow tape to re-mark the black and white wires to yellow.  These are **travelers** and will go on the brass screws of both switches (brass = yellow, get it? :)

Back in the busy switch box, the two red wires are nutted together. These are switched-hot, thus, red.

At this point, in each box, only 1 wire remains unattached.  And the black screw of each 3-way is empty.  *Do the obvious. And yer done.*

Comment: Thank you soo much.  I will give it a try.